# Effective memory management while querying from RDBMS with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, memory-management, sqlalchemy, string-concatenation

I have web service that need to query 10000 numbers from RDBMS and then return them in form of json. There are two issues here.

1. How to concatenate them in efficient way? I believe making result += next id is not good idea. Stackoverflow advice is to use .join - it is elegant, but I am not sure how it handles memory allocation
2. As far as I understand .fetchAll() could be somewht expensive here, because it initiall

Is it a way in Python to fetch row by row, take from row only one number and add to result in some efficient way.

Sample is a bit artificial, for simplicity purpose.

"Probably Memory hog" short solution that I have in mind look approximately like this:

```
s = text("select id from users where ... ")
connection = engine.connect()
with connection :
    rows = connection.execute(s).fetchall()
    return "["+','.join(str(r[0]) for r in rows) + "]" # json array
```

I know all this is looks artificial and it is not a good idea to fetech 10000 records at once, but I want to understand best practices of Python memory managemet.

In Java world where I came from there is class StringBuilder and way of fetching row by row from DB.

Comment: well what kind of performance profile are you looking for here?   Is this like happening 100 times a second in a web request (just use caching then) or some background job (should be fine)?  10K rows is not a crazy amount of data and if these are small simple rows, it's not terrible.    In Python, the biggest hit you'll get is individual function invocations so the single call to join() is probably pretty good.

Comment: As I have said sample is kind of artificial. Basically the task is 0 build web service (e.g. with flask @app.route('/s/get_data/param1/param2') ... return json. ) capable to pipe huge amount of data from DB to client with low memory usage. I.e. we have 1000 of requests per second and we want to minimize memory usage per request. I just want to understand what approach could be used in Python.

Comment: if you want to spit out 10000-record datafiles and need to do it 1000 req/sec you probably need to cache the datafiles, possibly generating them in some kind of asynchronous queue depending on how much variety there is to them.

Comment: Yes I know about caching. I know workarounds. I am currently studying Python and asking questions about Python.